# Wrong x axis on TensorBoard graphics

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new to TensorFlow and discouraged a bit by TensorBoard summaries. 
Here's a simple example (from Jupyter notebook cell):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

!rm ./test/*
tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.get_variable('gs', initializer=tf.zeros_initializer, shape=(), trainable=False)
inc_x = tf.assign_add(x, 1, use_locking=True)
tf.summary.scalar('step', inc_x)

const = tf.constant(1)
tf.summary.scalar('const', const)

summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./test')        
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(100):
        _summary, _, _inc_x = sess.run([summary, const, inc_x])
        writer.add_summary(_summary, i)

!tensorboard --logdir ./test/
```

I exepcted to see 2 graphics, where x axis takes values from `0` to `100` (depending from `i`). But in TensorBoard x axis takes values from `[0;70]` 
(see the screenshot) and if I remove constant evaluation, the upper bound will change to `90`.

What am I doing wrong and how should trustable summary be built?

[image: TensorBoard report: check Step field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. It isn't a displaying issue.

The `FileWriter` just should be closed manually here. Then it will dump all the rest events into the file. It isn't closed automatically because it's a plain code inside Jupyter Notebook and reference to `FileWriter` still exists.